# Using target files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

Suddenly I found existance of target files and got confused by using them.
Found many targets in directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0`

My project file `mypro.vcxpro` looks also uses the same syntax.

I need to create simple task that copies file after build event

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory)\ChangeLog.txt" 
      DestinationFolder="\\Path_on_network\Development" 
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true">
</Target>
```

But where I should place this task - to my project file `mypro.vcxpro` or I need to create new `.target` file and somehow link to project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about .vcxpro files, but usually .csproj builds calls the Build meta target that calls Something like `BeforeBuild`, `DoBuild` and `AfterBuild` targets.

The `AfterBuild` task is called but do nothing by default, usually you could override the `AfterBuild` target in your project file. Another way to do that is by using the properties GUI window and to fill the `PostBuildEvents` part. The code you put in there ends up in the `AfterBuild` target in your project files.

This is how it works for csproj project files but it should be quite the same for other project files.

You should not edit the targets files located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0` but rather read them and implement the correct Targets in your project files.